# Apache2 application php session can't be killed

Tags: server, apache2, php, session

I have php application running on my server, which many users can login, edit and logout using web access (apache2)

I am trying to kill (end) all currently opened sessions (to make all users login again),

I tried both ways, but the sessions are still running:

- I tried to restart the apache2
- I tried to remove sessions from "`/var/lib/php5`"

Comment: In what order did you tried these things?

Comment: at first i tired to restart apache2 only, didn't work. then i tried to clear all sessions in `/var/lib/php5` and restarted apache2, didn't work also. the session is sill opened.

Answer (score 0):

Make new PHP file :

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
```

Execute, session.gc_max_lifetime sets lifetime of session. session.gc_probability sets probability that GC on sessions is executed.